# How do i get generated filename when calling the Spark SaveAsTextFile method

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, spark-streaming

I'am new to Spark, Hadoop and all what comes with. My global need is to build a real-time application that  get tweets and store them on HDFS in order to build a report based on HBase.

I'd like to get the generated filename when calling saveAsTextFile RRD method in order to import it to Hive.

Feel free to ask for further informations and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

saveAsTextFile will create a directory of sequence files. So if you give it path "hdfs://user/NAME/saveLocation", a folder called saveLocation will be created filled with sequence files. You should be able to load this into HBase simply by passing the directory name to HBase (sequenced files are a standard in Hadoop).

I do recommend you look into saving as a parquet though, they are much more useful than standard text files.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I may have forgotten to mention that I use Spark Streaming, so AFAIK there is no way to save files as parquet.  Also i am planning to use this script (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/hive/HiveFromSpark.scala) to automatically import my HDFS Data  into Hive. That's was the reason why i was interested in getting the name of the generated files (part-0000* files ) .  I'll try another method to import files as you told me.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, You saved your tweets to hdfs and now want the file names of those saved files. Correct me if I'm wrong

```
val filenames=sc.textfile("Your hdfs location where you saved your tweets").map(_._1)
```

This gives you an array of rdd's into ***filenames*** onto which you could do your operations. Im a newbie too to hadoop, but anyways...hope that helps